# Angular JS Common Place to Contain View Logic Shared by Multiple Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering what would be the best place to contain code such as the one below.

```
if (gameInfo.products[0].product_image_height / gameInfo.products[0].product_image_width > imageRatio) {
        $scope.largeImageCss = "large-image";   
        $scope.sectionType = "vertical_section";
    } else {            
        $scope.largeImageCss = "";
        $scope.sectionType = "horizontal_section";
    }
```

The problem is that as you can see it modified a {{largeImageCss}} in the view.

Now i need the same logic (exactly the same code) in a different controller which controls a different view.

Is there something like a helper/mixin which we can use for this purpose in an angular way.

I dont think service, factory, provider is the right place for this as this contains $scope manipulation of the current controller.

Comment: Why you dont using directive ? it reusable

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the same `$scope` object from within multiple controllers, or are you trying to have multiple controllers share the same logic to manipulate their respective `$scope` object in the same way? I went ahead and assumed the second case, so if you could answer this question it will help me improve my answer below.

Comment: It is the second case as you mentioned and i have implemented the exact same solution you have provided, however 
 $scope.largeImageCss = sharedProperties.getLargeImageCss(gameInfo, imageRatio);
    $scope.sectionType = sharedProperties.getSectionType(gameInfo, imageRatio);
These are still not Dry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is what is referred to in AngularJS as a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Although AngularJS has built-in services such as `$http`, `$compile`, and `$templateCache`, AngularJS allows you to create your own custom services.

Although you mention in your question that you don't feel a service is where a controller's logical manipulation should take place, I don't think it's a problem if you plan on using the same exact logical manipulation across multiple controllers. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can comment on whether or not my approach is the "Angular Way" or not. See the example below:

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.service('sharedProperties', function() {

    return {
        getLargeImageCss: function(info, ratio) {
            if(info.products[0].product_image_height / info.products[0].product_image_width > ratio) {
                return 'large-image';
            }
            else {
                return '';
            }
        },
        getSectionType: function(info, ratio) {
            if(info.products[0].product_image_height / info.products[0].product_image_width > ratio) {
                return 'vertical_section';
            }
            else {
                return 'horizontal_section';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**controllers.js:**

```
app.controller('controller1', ['$scope', 'sharedProperties', function($scope, sharedProperties) {

    $scope.largeImageCss = sharedProperties.getLargeImageCss(gameInfo, imageRatio);
    $scope.sectionType = sharedProperties.getSectionType(gameInfo, imageRatio);
}]);

app.controller('controller2', ['$scope', 'sharedProperties', function($scope, sharedProperties) {

    $scope.largeImageCss = sharedProperties.getLargeImageCss(gameInfo, imageRatio);
    $scope.sectionType = sharedProperties.getSectionType(gameInfo, imageRatio);
}]);
```

To make the above code even more concise, since the same condition is used in both of the service's functions, you group the `getLargeImageCss` and `getSectionType` functions into one `getImageInfo` function that returns both the `largeImageCss` and `sectionType` within one object.